# How to fix Activator.CreateInstance failing with MissingMethodException "Constructor on type not found"?

Tags: c#, wpf, activator, createinstance

I'm trying to create a custom User Control with the following:

```
var panel = new GenericAccordionPanel<ZoneReport, ZonesPanel, ZonesVM>(myVm.ZonesVm);
```

`GenericAccordionPanel` is defined as:

```
public class GenericAccordionPanel<THeader, TBody, TViewModel> : UserControl
{
    public Accordion Accordion { get; set; }

    public GenericAccordionPanel(TViewModel vmItem)
    {
        this.Accordion = new Accordion();

        //the constructor for ZoneReport(THeader) takes a ZonesVM (vmItem) as a parameter.
        var zr = (THeader)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(THeader), new { vmItem });

        var exp = new Expander { Header = zr };

        Accordion.Children.Add(exp);

        base.Content = Accordion;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Activator.CreateInstance` is failing with the following `MissingMethodException`:

> Constructor on type '[namespace].Zones.ZoneReport' not found.

How can I create an isntance of `ZoneReport`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new { vmItem }` should be `new object[]{ vmItem }`.

At the moment you're calling [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) with an anonymous type as the second argument, not an array of parameters.

Since the second argument (for the overload you want) is actually a `params` parameter, you can also just use plain `vmItem` and the compiler will generate the array:

```
 var zr = (THeader)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(THeader), vmItem);
```

Comment: You are a man to whom I owe a beer. This is correct, thank you. For the record, the first part - `new[]{ vmItem }` - doesn't work for me, but removing the array declaration - `(typeof(THeader), vmItem);
` - works perfectly.

Comment: Got a bit sloppy and left the `object` out. I'll fix the post.